# VisualStudio ToolBox c шаблонами кода

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Просматривая на [странице документации](http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/) к MVVMlight первое видео (доклад с techdays2010) на 9-ой минуте заприметил заинтересовавший меня функционал студии, а именно:

Докладчик находясь на вкладке редактирования C# кода держит открытым toolBox в котором у него лежат шаблоны кода которые он простым перетаскиванием добавляет в свой код.

Собственно возможна ли такая функциональность у 15-ой студии и, если да, то как добавлять шаблоны кода в ToolBox? И будет ли работать с XAML разметкой?

PS: Об аналогичных вариантах создания и использования шаблонов когда с помощью IntelliSense и/или ReSharper я в курсе.

Comment: Просто выделите нужный текст (код) в Студии и перетащите мышкой в Toolbox. Потом также мышкой можете перетаскивать шаблон из тулбокса в редактор. Или дважды кликнуть по нему.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov: точняк. Спасибо. PS: Оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы сделать такой шаблон, достаточно выделить нужный текст (код) в любом текстовом редакторе, например, в Студии и перетащить мышкой в Toolbox. Можно использовать стандартный копипаст: Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V.